# pip installation within a python script isn't recognized

Tags: python, docker, pip, pythonpath, python-packaging

I'm installing a package within a python process (which runs within a docker container) via a subprocess call into a custom directory `/tmp/custom_libs` which I have already added to `$PYTHONPATH`:

```
subprocess.check_call(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "--target=/tmp/custom_libs","--no-cache-dir", "my_package-0.1.tar.gz"]
```

This finishes successfully. However I can't import the modules after the installation is finished. i.e.:

```
import my_package
```

fails with: 
`ImportError: No module named 'my_package'`

(I verified that `sys.path` does include `/tmp/custom_libs` and that the modules are indeed located in that directory).

What's strange is that when I open a different python session, it *can* import `my_package` and everything is working fine. So my only guess is that something is stale because the installation happened within the same python session, but I can't figure out what that can be and how to *refresh things*. Any ideas?

p.s.: I'm using python3.5 if that helps.